# Live iPhone app not showing ANY adWhirl ads

Tags: iphone, adwhirl

I implemented adWhirl ads in my iPhone app.
During testing ads showed great from all networks, including house ads.
I released the app, I have active users (because they submit high scores)
But... No income showing in network reports and when I use the app, no ads show.
Did I forget to flip a switch somewhere?

Thanks!
Hanaan

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse my utter stupidity...
I forgot to set up the C Flags in my target's build settings to indicate that it is the lite version...